# Does it make sense to declare variables as private with getters/setters for class member definitions declared within a public class?

Tags: java

```
class Foo {
    String bar;
    // private String bar;
}

public class A {
    public void method1() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        // foo.bar; or foo.getBar(); which is preferable

    }
}
```

Does it make sense to declare variables as private with getters/setters for class member definitions (e.g. should `bar` be declared as private in `Foo` or should it be just declared as `String bar`)? I would prefer to remove them, sense they cannot be accessed outside this class anyway. What would be preferable?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Foo isn't an inner class at the moment anyway. Please give a short but complete example, including the getters/setters you want to remove.

Comment: @Jon - Will remove the inner class tag, this is for a class declared in the same class as "A"

Comment: @Joe: Changing the example would be better than changing the tags... your question is still unclear.

Comment: @Jon - modified the question text

Comment: @Joe: Well now class `A` doesn't seem to serve any purpose at all, and you haven't said what `bar` is used for. We simply don't have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @Jon - modified the question text

Comment: @Joe: `Foo` is visible to the entire package (not just `A`) when declared like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using getters and settings to access/mutate a private field member is standard OO practice. It allows the inner workings of the class to change while maintaining its public interface.

If you were to access/mutate `bar` by making it directly available as part of the public interface (by making it public) it may seem fine now but what happens when, months later, you decide you want to add some validation to `bar`? Maybe you don't want `bar` to ever be set to `null`. How could you achieve that? If you use getters and setters, all you would need to do is change your setter to throw an exception if an attempt is made to set `bar` to `null`. If you mutate `bar` directly, you couldn't do that. More drastically you may decide that `bar` is no longer required at all!

Getters and setters do not imply that a field member of the same name and type exists internally of the class. They tell you only that the class has a property that can be accessed/mutated and dictate nothing about the way in which the class performs that internally. This gives you a great deal of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for data access, not having getters/setters should be ok (some purists may disagree). And your class should be able to access private members of inner class so you can keep them private.

Answer (score 1):

Make Foo an **inner class** and don't have getters/setters:

```
public class A {
    private class Foo {
        String bar;
    }

    public void method1() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar = "x";
    }
}
```

It is OK design because Foo is only visible within A - it's no worse than accessing private fields directly within a class instead of via the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Please first answer: Why does `method1` need to know about `foo`'s `bar`? Why does `method1` need to know that `Foo`s even **have** `bar`s in the first place?

Comment: Why shouldn't it know about foo's bar? I have some functionality which needs to uses the bar member variable in Foo. I am not sure why this is relevant here. I need clarification on whether I should access bar using a getter or should I avoid getters and access it via foo.bar?

Comment: Because not knowing about the members of an object is the **default** in OOP. It is relevant because you are apparently attempting to write OO code, and there are ways that we do these things. Functionality "which needs to use the bar member variable in Foo" is, generally, functionality that **should be provided by Foo itself**.